# _.cloneDeep is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on one small JavaScript, jQuery project. It is Tic Tac Toe game. I want the computer to play hard against the human. For that sake, I used minmix function, which is a very popular function for a game I think.

Here is my HTML code

```
 <header id="showcase">
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe Game</h1>
        <div class="game-container">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <section class="section">
                    <div class="box" data-i=0 data-j=0></div>
                    <div class="box" data-i=0 data-j=1></div>
                    <div class="box" data-i=0 data-j=2></div>
                </section>
                <section class="section">
                    <div class="box" data-i=1 data-j=0></div>
                    <div class="box" data-i=1 data-j=1></div>
                    <div class="box" data-i=1 data-j=2></div>
                </section>
                <section class="section">
                    <div class="box" data-i=2 data-j=0></div>
                    <div class="box" data-i=2 data-j=1></div>
                    <div class="box" data-i=2 data-j=2></div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="winner"></div>
        <div class="button">
            <button id="restart">Restart</button>
        </div>
    </header>
```

I am using very long process, but I will add the minmax function here.

```
function minmax(newGrid, depth, player) {
  const gameState= gameOver(newGrid);

  if (gameState === false){
    const values= [];

    for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j<3;j++){
        const gridCopy = _.cloneDeep(newGrid);
        if (gridCopy[i][j]!=='') continue;
        gridCopy[i][j]=player;
        const value = minmax(gridCopy,depth+1,(player===PLAYER_TOKEN)?COMPUTER_TOKEN:PLAYER_TOKEN);
        values.push({
        cost:value,
      cell: {
        i:i,
        j:j
      }
    });
      }
    }

    if (player === COMPUTER_TOKEN) {
      const max = _.maxBy(values, (v) => {
        return v.cost;
      });
      if (depth === 0) {
        return max.cell;
      }
      else {
        return max.cost;
      }
    }
    else {
      const min = _.minBy(values, (v) => {
        return v.cost;
      });
      if (depth === 0) {
        return min.cell;
      }
      else {
        return min.cost;
      }
    }
  }
  else if (gameState === null){
    return 0;
  }
  else if (gameState===PLAYER_TOKEN) {
    return depth - 10;
  }
  else if (gameState===COMPUTER) {
    return 10 - depth;
  }
}

function computerMove(){
  return minmax(grid,0,COMPUTER_TOKEN);
}
```

I am getting an error in the console, which I do not understand.

```
Uncaught TypeError: _.cloneDeep is not a function
```

I added Underscore JS also but not working

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/0.10.0/lodash.
```

If you want to see this project in action for more detail, here is the [link](https://codepen.io/ziaullahzia/full/wqpGxW/).

Comment: it appears the issue is that you haven't added underscore

Comment: _.cloneDeep is from lodash or underscore.

Comment: I do not understand. It is from lodash

Comment: This problem is still here. need help.

Comment: It is a different library

Comment: Can you please check, I past the link to code

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep <-- Lodash , https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore.deepclone <-- Underscore

Comment: Did not got it, I am new to that

Comment: This is underscore issue. Can any one please check the link